# How do I filter an array at codeigniter or php

Tags: php, arrays, linq, codeigniter, filter

I have an options table

```
Option_ID | option_Type | Option_Text
----------|-------------|------------
1         | gender      | Male        
2         | gender      | Female      
3         | color       | black
4         | color       | white
5         | color       | red
6         | color       | blue
```

And I am getting all rows to my controller. But I want to filter array which is loading database rows as option_type

I can read

```
foreach($optionList as $row){
    if ($row->gender){ echo "<option value='".$row->id."'>".$row->text."</opiton>}
}
```

But I dont want if statement. Is there any way filter as color without if statement

Comment: $this->db->get_where('table',['option_Type'=>'color'])->result() ?

Comment: There are more then 10 option at one page. ıts means connect to db over and over again. So I want to filter array not db

Comment: So, this is good:
foreach($optionList as $row){
            echo ($row->option_Type=='gender')?"<option value='".$row->id."'>".$row->text."</opiton>":'';
        }

Comment: Yes its good. And I am looking for best

Comment: show your model code - somewhere you've to prepare your optionList Array

Comment: Its not a special model. $optionList=$this->db->get('optionTable');

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you don't mind using an if condition in the solution.  You just don't want to needlessly iterate while only echoing a few rows in the array.

I see that you are working with an array of objects, you can cast as array or try to workaround any array functions that choke on objects.

```
$options=array(
    array('Option_ID'=>1,'option_Type'=>'gender','Option_Text'=>'Male'),
    array('Option_ID'=>2,'option_Type'=>'gender','Option_Text'=>'Female'),
    array('Option_ID'=>3,'option_Type'=>'color','Option_Text'=>'black'),
    array('Option_ID'=>4,'option_Type'=>'color','Option_Text'=>'white'),
    array('Option_ID'=>5,'option_Type'=>'color','Option_Text'=>'red'),
    array('Option_ID'=>6,'option_Type'=>'color','Option_Text'=>'blue')
);

// collect all option_Type values, retain unique values, declare filter as $f
foreach(array_unique(array_column($options,"option_Type")) as $f){
    echo ucfirst($f),": <select name=$f>";
    foreach(array_filter($options,function($a)use($f){if($a["option_Type"]==$f)return $a;}) as $row){
        echo "<option value='",$row["Option_ID"],"'>",$row["Option_Text"],"</option>";
    }
    echo "</select><br><br>";
}
```

This will ensure every iteration is useful.  [Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3f77b5e0b3b788af4ccbca957e7d2c70219158b8)

---

Non-LINQ **Second Attempt** ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dc3bc7e61e9b2a16fdc811b3d42383de101f49a4)):

`array_filter` seems to work for me with my subarrays cast as objects.

```
foreach(array_filter($options,function($a){return $a->option_Type=='gender';}) as $o){
    echo "{$o->Option_Text}<br>";
}
```

This makes no wasted iterations and displays:

```
black
white
red
blue
```

Comment: @hbaltuntel If this is satisfactory for your use case, please award me the green tick (and possibly an upvote for being helpful).  If there is still something the matter, please explain.

Comment: This solution is clearly helpful. But I use each option Types at different location, different pages. And my way is quite simple. I code MVC C# the same time. There is something call LINQ. And code is just like this -> "$optionList.Where($option_type=gender)". I am looking for something like this,

Comment: @hbaltuntel  Okay.  Perhaps it would be best to refine your question with your commented details and add a LINQ tag to draw the appropriate audience.  If my answer is not useful, I will likely delete it to reduce SO bloat.  Please copy your comment to your question at your earliest convenience.

Comment: @hbaltuntel  I have just posted a second attempt, again it is not a LINQ solution, but it is a relatively small function that seems to do the job.  If it doesn't work for you please let me know.